# MySQLのCREATEでエラー

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQLにてテーブル作成のためにcreate文を実行したところ、エラーになります。
エラーNoは1064(42000)のシンタックスエラーなので、構文に問題があると思いますが、
様々なサイトと見比べても問題が発見できませんでした。
問題がある部分をご教示いただければと存じます。
SQL文を添付します。

```
create table news(
id int unsigned not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
pub_date date(10) not null,
title VARCHAR(200) not null,
content VARCHAR(2000) not null,
user VARCHAR(100) not null,
prc_date datetime(100) not null,
status VARCHAR(10) not null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

予約語にひっかかっている可能性があります。

---

エラーメッセージで検索すると、例えば以下のページがヒットします。

[ERROR 1064 (42000)→構文ミスが見つからない→予約語が原因かも](https://qiita.com/djkazunoko/items/3c6c70d91d0f1b49b61e)

MySQL のドキュメントで予約語のページを眺めてみると、今回の場合は `status` が該当しそうです。

[キーワードと予約語 | MySQL 8.0 リファレンスマニュアル](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/ja/keywords.html)

回避策としては別の名前を使うか、該当箇所をバッククォートで括る方法が考えられます。

```
create table news(
  ...
  `status` VARCHAR(10) not null
);
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。date、datetaimeと合わせて対応して解決しました。

Answer (score 1):

dateとdatetimeは()はマストではない気がします

参考
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/ja/datetime.html

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE dt (
->     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
->     col DATETIME NOT NULL
-> ) AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

利用する際もdatetimeは6までのようです
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/ja/fractional-seconds.html

```
MySQL では、マイクロ秒 (6 桁) までの精度で、TIME、DATETIME および TIMESTAMP 値の小数秒がサポートされています:
```

なので、不要であればdateとdatetimeの()を削除して試してみてください

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。予約語対応と合わせて対応したら解決しました。